# Merging rows in R based on several parameters

Tags: r, merge, apply

I have a dataframe `df` which contains close to 100,000 showing the list of my program's contacts. The list has a column showing the program `program` and organization `OrgName` with which the contact is associated. It also has a set of three columns showing whether or not the contact is associated with the role identified in the column name: `Role_Primary`, `Role_Comms`, `Role_Signatory`. Whenever a contact is in more than one program or has more than one role in the program another line is created for that contact with the program and contact role field values changing. See example below.

```
First   Last    C_ID    OrgName O_ID Program    Role_Primary    Role_Comms  Role_Signatory
John    Smith   10045   Acme    901  Buildings  X       
John    Smith   10045   Acme    901  Buildings                  X   
John    Smith   10045   Acme    901  Homes      X       
Teddy   Bush    10046   Acme    901  Buildings  X       
Teddy   Bush    10046   Acme    901  Buildings                              X
Jess    Clinton 10050   Consult 904  Homes                                  X
Jess    Clinton 10050   Consult 904  Homes      X       
Jess    Clinton 10050   Consult 904  Homes      X
```

For presentation purposes I am trying to minimize the number of lines. Specifically, if a contact is in the same organization and the same program, I only want the contact to appear on one line (versus several at the moment) and to notate the contact roles in the associated columns. See below.

```
First   Last    C_ID    OrgName O_ID Program    Role_Primary    Role_Comms  Role_Signatory
John    Smith   10045   Acme    901  Buildings  X               X   
John    Smith   10045   Acme    901  Homes      X       
Teddy   Bush    10046   Acme    901  Buildings  X               X
Jess    Clinton 10050   Consult 904  Homes      X               X           X
```

To recreate the two tables above:

```
 table1<-structure(list(First = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Jess", "John", "Teddy"), class = "factor"), 
    Last = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Bush", 
    "Clinton", "Smith"), class = "factor"), C_ID = c(10045L, 
    10045L, 10045L, 10046L, 10046L, 10050L, 10050L, 10050L), 
    OrgName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Acme", 
    "Consult"), class = "factor"), O_ID = c(901L, 901L, 901L, 
    901L, 901L, 904L, 904L, 904L), Program = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Buildings", "Homes"
    ), class = "factor"), Role_Primary = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "X"), class = "factor"), 
    Role_Comms = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "X"), class = "factor"), Role_Signatory = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "X"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("First", 
"Last", "C_ID", "OrgName", "O_ID", "Program", "Role_Primary", 
"Role_Comms", "Role_Signatory"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

table2<-structure(list(First = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Jess", 
"John", "Teddy"), class = "factor"), Last = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bush", "Clinton", "Smith"), class = "factor"), 
    C_ID = c(10045L, 10045L, 10046L, 10050L), OrgName = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Acme", "Consult"), class = "factor"), 
    O_ID = c(901L, 901L, 901L, 904L), Program = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Buildings", "Homes"), class = "factor"), 
    Role_Primary = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "X", class = "factor"), 
    Role_Comms = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "X"), class = "factor"), Role_Signatory = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "X"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("First", 
"Last", "C_ID", "OrgName", "O_ID", "Program", "Role_Primary", 
"Role_Comms", "Role_Signatory"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: do you know how to use dplyr? if so, it'd be pretty easy to just convert all the `role` vars to integer flags (instead of "x"), then group by the non-`role` vars and create new `role` vars using summarise(). I can do it for u if u `dput()` a sample of ur data.

Comment: Chris I'm not familiar with how to do this with dplyr. I added dput data to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: looks like someone already answered. I assume that will answer will work for u. if not, just let me know

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
df <- data.table::fread("First      Last        C_ID        OrgName     O_ID    Program Role_Primary    Role_Comms  Role_Signatory
John        Smith       10045   Acme        901 Buildings   X       
John        Smith       10045   Acme        901 Buildings       X   
John        Smith       10045   Acme        901 Homes       X       
Teddy       Bush        10046   Acme        901 Buildings   X       
Teddy       Bush        10046   Acme        901 Buildings           X
Jess        Clinton     10050   Consult     904 Homes               X
Jess        Clinton     10050   Consult     904 Homes       X       
Jess        Clinton     10050   Consult     904 Homes       X       ")
```

**Code to merge rows:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(Role, Member, Role_Primary:Role_Signatory) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Member) & nchar(trimws(Member))>0) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(Role = factor(Role, unique(Role))) %>% 
  spread(Role, Member)
```

**Output**

```
First    Last  C_ID OrgName O_ID   Program Role_Primary Role_Comms Role_Signatory
1  Jess Clinton 10050 Consult  904     Homes            X       <NA>              X
2  John   Smith 10045    Acme  901 Buildings            X          X           <NA>
3  John   Smith 10045    Acme  901     Homes            X       <NA>           <NA>
4 Teddy    Bush 10046    Acme  901 Buildings            X       <NA>              X
```

Please note that the distinct() line is there because in the input example Jess Clinton has the same role listed twice.

Comment: I tried the solution by first importing the sample data you provided in df. Howver, that didn't read into R. I then tried implementing the solution using the dput data I provided in an edit to the original question. However, I received the following message:  Error in filter(., !is.na(Member) & nchar(trimws(Member)) > 0) : 
  object 'Member' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
>

Comment: To use the code here, you must have the packages installed that are used for this solution.  To input the data using fread, you must install the data.table package.  For the code to merge the rows, you must have dplyr and tidyr installed.  Are these 3 packages installed when you tried to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to make a unique identifier column, use this column to filter to unique rows saved as `df2`, and then use your full data from `df` to fill in missing values in `df2`.

```
library(dplyr)
#make a uniqueID  column by pasting any of the relevant unique values together
df$uniqueID<-paste0(df$C_ID,df$OrgName, df$Program)
#remove duplicate rows, store as df2 
df2<-df[!duplicated(df$uniqueID),]
```

Use index of the `uniqueID` to find `any()` X's for the same `uniqueID` in `df2`.

```
for(id in 1:nrow(df2)){
Xfind<-df$Role_Primary[df$uniqueID %in% df2$uniqueID[id]]
if (any(Xfind=="X")){df2$Role_Primary[id]<-"X"}
Xfind2<-df$Role_Signatory[df$uniqueID %in% df2$uniqueID[id]] 
if (any(Xfind2=="X")){df2$Role_Signatory[id]<-"X"}
Xfind3<-df$Role_Comms[df$uniqueID %in% df2$uniqueID[id]]
if (any(Xfind3=="X")){df2$Role_Comms[id]<-"X"}
}
```

This will give you the desired output as:

```
df2
```